# Swift generate xcodeproj for swift package with Realm dependency cpp parse error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I made a swift package with Realm (3.18.0) as dependency. I can build, test and include my package in others projects without any problems.

Recently I tried to automate my test in order to run it into a script. I've found this steps:

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
xcodebuild test -destination 'name=iPhone 11' -scheme 'MyLibrary-Package'
```

I can generate my project but after that I cannot build it, I got errors from RealmCore on file `terminate.cpp` such as

```
ParseIssue: Expected ";" after expression
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: Invalid suffix .5 on floating constant (Expanded from macro 'REALM_VER_CHUNK')
```

On my package settings, iOS supported version is 11. Swift language version is unspecified.

Any idea about why I get this error ?
Thanks you very much